# I can't read a responseStream from a HttpError

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 web Api with .Net Framework 4.0 and C#.

I'm having problems when I try to get a response stream from a `HttpError`.

Here, I generate the `HttpError`:

```
m_ExceptionLoggerHelper.LogException("ProductionOrderManagementController", "DoBatchPreparation", Singleton.AutomationServiceVM.COGErrors);

HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(Singleton.AutomationServiceVM.COGErrors) { { "CustomErrorCode", 4 } };
response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, myCustomError);
```

With Fiddler, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRnVlbnRlc1xBdXRvbWF0aW9uTWlkZGxld2FyZVxzcmNcQXV0b21hdGlvbk1pZGRsZXdhcmUuV2ViLkFwaVxhcGlccHJvZHVjdGlvbk9yZGVyc01hbmFnZW1lbnRcTUNHXzIwMTQwODI4MDgyOTQ4XGRvQmF0Y2hQcmVwYXJhdGlvbg==?=
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 28 Aug 2014 06:32:36 GMT
Content-Length: 70

{"Message":"Preparation Failed SessionLocked\r\n","CustomErrorCode":4}
```

Here I catch the exception:

```
catch (WebException exception)
{
    Stream responseStream = exception.Response.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + result);
    }
}
```

I'm having problems here, `new StreamReader(responseStream)`, because I get an `ArgumentException`. While debugging, I check `responseStream` and I see the `CanRead` property is false.

And `'responseStream.Length' throw an excepción type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're seeing this behavior because the stream has already been read elsewhere.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because the response stream has already been consumed elsewhere.

If you want to read the stream multiple times, copy its contents to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) first. You can then read the `MemoryStream` as often as you want.